# EntityManager is null inside Pojo class in ejb container

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb, entitymanager

I have a Java web service module and ejb modulein netbeans (All part of an enterprise application). the web service is consuming the ejb class using @EJB injection.
Inside the ejb module i have a TransactionManager class which is not an enterprise bean. just a POJO class. I am trying to inject the EntityManager using

```
    @PersistanceContext(unitName = "testPU")
    EntityManager em;
```

but the em is allways null. 
I am calling the TransactionManager class from by bean, and if i declare the EntityManager declaration in bean class, it injects just fine in the bean class. but in POJO it is always null.

I am new to EJB (using version JEE7) . can u please guide me ?

Reply to Shailendra : 
my bean and pojo are in the same jar file, and it has the bean.xml and persistence.xml.
I tried to make the TransactionManager class as bean, using @Stateless and @Local, but there are some pojo classes in between the ejb class and the TransactionManager class, and when i tried to access the TransactionManager class from its parent pojo class using 
        @EJB
        TransactionManager transactionManager;
this object too returned null.

Dear Shilendra, thanks for the reply 
Below is my EJB class

```
    @Stateless
    @Local(IMyService.class)
    public class MyService extends MyBase implements IMyService
    {
        MyComponent component = null;
        public void doSomething(X x)
        {
             component = new MyComponent();
             component.doSomething(x);
        }
    }
```

I have a POJO class as MyComponent

```
    public class MyComponent extends MyBase implements IMyComponent
    {
        TransactionManager tManager = null;
        public void doSomething(X x)
        {
            tManager = new TransactionManager();
            tManager.doSomething(x);
        }
    }
```

And The TransactionManager class is the class that i want Dependency Injection done for PersistenceContext

```
    public class TransactionManager extends MyBase implements ITransactionManager
    {
          @PersistenceContext(unitName="TestPU")
          EntityManager em;
          public void doSomething(X x)
          {
               em.persist(x);
          }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

POJO isn't managed by the container. Whereas the bean is managed by the container & is responsible for injecting resources.

You can try JNDI lookup to lookup resources for non-managed custom classes for which container isn't responsible.

Comment: Hi,
Can you give me a sample

Comment: @vilsad I don't do much with CDI, you can try `@Inject EntityManager` see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is be that your POJO is not managed by the container. If your container supports CDI (Context dependency injection) then declare your bean  in a bean archive (have beans.xml in META-INF or WEB-INF) in order to be managed.

Comment: Can you post the relevant class structure

Comment: I posted tge relevent code for the issue, While searching i got a rumor that this issue is particular to GlassFish (some search pointed that way). but i cannot test it with another server because i couldn't find a JEE7 compatible one (Tomcat / JBoss).

Comment: I tried to make the TransactionManager class as bean by adding (at) Stateless to the top of class declaration and (at) Local to the top of Interface declaration. Then getting EntityManagerFactory by Injecting (at) PersistenceUnit. but this also returned null;

Answer (score 0):

You should use the @Inject Annotation instead of creating the instances with the new-operator.

1. create the `\WEB-INF\beans.xml` (there is a wizard for it in Netbeans) and set
   `bean-discovery-mode="all"`
2. This is the code for your "MyService": yours or mine? :-)

   ```
    @Stateless
    @Local(IMyService.class)
    public class MyService extends MyBase implements IMyService {

        @Inject
        private MyComponent component;

        public void doSomething(X x)
        {
             component = new MyComponent();
             component.doSomething(x);
        }
    }
   ```
3. And this is your "MyComponent" :-)

   ```
   public class MyComponent extends MyBase implements IMyComponent
   {
       @Inject 
       private TransactionManager tManager;

       public void doSomething(X x)
       {
           tManager = new TransactionManager();
           tManager.doSomething(x);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Would you please accept the answer? Just click on the grayed check mark besides the answer.