# JPA client throws NullPointerException related to injection of EntityManager

Tags: java, jpa

I am learning Java EE and generated the entities from GlassFish sample database, I built a simple client but having a problem trying to run my test JPA code below:

```
public class JPAMain {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="EJBClient1PU")
    private static EntityManager em;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());
        em.find(Customer.class, 1);
        //em.createNamedQuery("Customer.findAll");
        //List c = em.createNamedQuery("Customer.findAll").getResultList();
        //log.info(((Customer)c.get(0)).getName());
    }
}
```

This is persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="EJBClient1PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>ejbclient1.jpa.ProductCode</class>
    <class>ejbclient1.jpa.MicroMarket</class>
    <class>ejbclient1.jpa.Manufacturer</class>
    <class>ejbclient1.jpa.Product</class>
    <class>ejbclient1.jpa.Customer</class>
    <class>ejbclient1.jpa.DiscountCode</class>
    <class>ejbclient1.jpa.PurchaseOrder</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="app"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="app"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

When I run the code it gives the following error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainer.launch(AppClientContainer.java:446)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.AppClientFacade.main(AppClientFacade.java:166)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ejbclient1.JPAMain.main(JPAMain.java:23)
    ... 6 more
Java Result: 1
```

The problem is this line `em.find(Customer.class, 1);`

I don't really know what is causing that problem

UPDATE:

I changed EntityManager to be not static as below, but still getting the same error:

```
public class JPAMain {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="EJBClient1PU")
    private EntityManager em;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new JPAMain().work();
        //em.createNamedQuery("Customer.findAll");
        //List c = em.createNamedQuery("Customer.findAll").getResultList();
        //log.info(((Customer)c.get(0)).getName());
    }
    public void work(){
        Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());
        em.find(Customer.class, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks to me like your EntityManager injection isn't working, therefore `em` is probably null. What type of class is JPAMain? Anyway, I'm not 100% certain, but I'd bet that injection into `static` fields doesn't work.

Comment: @HeinBlöd it's just a class sits inside an Enterprise Application Client.

Comment: So EntityManager is null, so it isn't injected correctly, so return to documentation about injecting EntityManager and see what is different ... such as the "static" as mentioned above

Comment: I changed EntityManager to be not static but still gives the same error.

Comment: So is JPAMain some kind of managed component, like an EJB or a CDI bean, or even a JAX-RS resource class? The injection won't work with a POJO, cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397822/entitymanager-is-null-inside-pojo-class-in-ejb-container. Edit: Never mind - seeing you have a `main` method and obtain a JPAMain instance using `new` tells me that it isn't a managed component. You should read up on those subjects first, but I can tell you for sure that injection never works (afaik) in any object that you created yourself in application code using `new`.

Comment: @HeinBlöd ok that makes sense.